# visitor counter which only counts the unique visitors for 24 hours and end the session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, counter

i'm creating statistics overview system which shows the statistics of a site in a bar chart. What I need is a visitor counter which only counts the unique visitors. In this case, unique means one person can only view a post in a day(24 hours), the unique ID should only be valid for 24 hours after which destroy. please i need help on how i can write the code in PHP, codeigniter preferably, been trying this since yesterday. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something? show us your code so we can help you

Comment: no, i don't even know how to go about it, but i understand the flow

Comment: unfortunately stack isn't for these kinds of questions; they go into the too broad category because largely they are unanswerable and because this isn't a code writing service. They also don't adhere to the MVCE guidelines

Comment: Have you tried using google analytics? Can access the api to get data from there to work with yourself

Comment: don't want to use google analytic, want to do it manually